# Catch lost focus event on dockable pane with CMFCPropertyGrid

Tags: c++, mfc, propertygrid, dockable-windows

I have a trouble with `CMFCPropertyGrid` placed on a dockable pane. When I edit value in the grid and do not finish the edit then click on the document's view, the value stills old. To update it I (as a user) have click the dockable pane again and enter on the value to finish edit and update the value. Everything works fine when I click on the white space of the grid while editing value.

What I tried. I tried to catch `ON_WM_KILLFOCUS` and `ON_WM_ACTIVATE` of the dockable pane. But these message are not cought when click on the document's view as I described.

How can I process the events to call the grid's `EndEdit` method when clicking somewhere outside the dockable pane during text edits in `CMFCPropertyGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is likely being edited inside an Edit control. I would look for the [EN_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification code.

Comment: It doesn't work. Looks like all controls have focus when I click the document view. Wait, I see that when I move the mouse outside the dockable pane I notice that the header flashes and is drawn in another color.

Comment: You are right, it didn't worked first time because I use custom edit box within property grid property. I changed my `CEdit`'s id to `AFX_PROPLIST_ID_INPLACE` and it worked. Finally. There are no docs for that. MFC looks like a nightmare after Qt event when 1.5 years of MFC working experience passed. I am terribly angry.